# Authentication with GitLab CI in a one stage Kaniko build using two separate artifactorys

Tags: docker, authentication, gitlab-ci, artifactory, kaniko

I'm building a Docker image with Kaniko.
I would like to use two separate private artifactories for my GitLab CI/CD pipeline:

1. One from which the Dockerfile takes its source image (Artifactory1/Repo1)
2. One to which the pipeline will push the ready image (Artifactory2/Repo2)

Both have separate credentials.

My question is, how could I add the login credentials for the second, destination artifactory? I have tried with -u -p flags, and also with a separate line, did not work.

As of now my gitlab-ci.yml code looks something like this:

```
image:
    name: artifactory1/kaniko/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
stages:
    - build
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - env
        - KANIKOCFG="\"auths\":{\"artifactory1/repo1/\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${ARTIFACTORY1_USER}" "${ARTIFACTORY1_PASS}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}"
        - KANIKOCFG="{ ${KANIKOCFG} }"
        - echo ${KANIKOCFG} >> /kaniko/.docker/config.json
        - /kaniko/executor --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ --destination artifactory2/repo2/finalimage:1.0.0
```

Both artifactory1 and artfactory2 credentials are known and added to GitLab as variables, something like this:

```
ARTIFACTORY1_USER
ARTIFACTORY1_PASS
ARTIFACTORY2_USER
ARTIFACTORY2_PASS
```

I'm always getting an authentication error for REPO2 that I cant push there. Of course now it does not work because I could not set authentication up in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be much easier for you to build with Kaniko and push docker images through the JFrog CLI.

See the example [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/docker-oci-examples/kaniko-example).

On top of that with JFrog CLI you can configure multiple Artifactory registries and distinguish between them with '--server-id'
See the documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory).

Comment: Thank you, this solution was not known to me, I will check and try.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem on the file `/kaniko/.docker/config.json`

The config.json should look like this:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "$REPO1_URL": {
      "username": "$ARTIFACTORY1_USER",
      "password": "$ARTIFACTORY1_PASS"
    },
    "$REPO2_URL": {
      "username": "$ARTIFACTORY2_USER",
      "password": "$ARTIFACTORY2_PASS"
    }
  }
}
```

Give a try on the following code to update your config.json file:

```
script:
  - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$REPO1_URL\":{\"username\":\"$ARTIFACTORY1_USER\",\"password\":\"$ARTIFACTORY1_PASS\"},\"$REPO2_URL\":{\"username\":\"$ARTIFACTORY2_USER\",\"password\":\"$ARTIFACTORY1_PASS\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that, and will come back with the results.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work this way either. It probably would have worked if the repositories would have been compeletly different but as I read through issue descriptions, Kaniko cannot handle the below situation:   
   
`Repo to pull from: "example.com/registryA"`
`Repo to push to: "example.com/registryB"`

So note how the example.com is the same in both entries. Is there a workaround for this as well?